# VSCode - Blazor SyncFusion Components not found by linter

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-code, blazor, syncfusion

VSCode is not finding any SyncFusion (<Sf... />) components.

I have imported all in _imports.razor:

```cs
@using System.Net.Http
@using System.Net.Http.Json
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Forms
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Routing
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web.Virtualization
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Http
@using Microsoft.JSInterop
@using CleverscoutIntranet.Client
@using CleverscoutIntranet.Client.Shared
@using CleverscoutIntranet.Client.Shared.Topbar

@using Syncfusion.Blazor
@using Syncfusion.Blazor.Calendars
@using Syncfusion.Blazor.Buttons
@using Syncfusion.Blazor.Grids
@using Syncfusion.Blazor.DropDowns
@using Syncfusion.Blazor.Inputs
@using Syncfusion.Blazor.Spinner
```

It is compiling without any problems, but the linter yells this at me:

```md
    Found markup element with unexpected name 'SfTextBox'.
    If this is intended to be a component, add a @using directive for its namespace.(RZ10012)
```

Every component has this warning, so does every line of code have the warning waves below it, which makes the text unreadable. Importing those namespaces right in the component and not in _imports.razor does not fix the issue.

I created the project with the extension from syncfusion:
Blazor VSCode Extensions - Syncfusion

My editor looks like this:
[vscode distracting warning styles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8HsNN.jpg)
Code from: [blazor.syncfusion.com](https://blazor.syncfusion.com/demos/datagrid/overview?theme=bootstrap)

I was not able to find any setting in vscode to disable the c# linter, i use the default c# extension from microsoft.

Answer (score 0):

As far I know, Visual Studio does support _imports.razor. So they will be shown right, but Rider 2021.2.3 doesn't support it yet. A while  ago I tried VS Code unsuccessful. If you  could work with Visual Studio, that solves the linter problem.